# How do you detect if a button is visible in pygame, given the button doesn't leave the screen?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a function called `isVisible` for my class called `DrawButton` currently it doesn't work as intended, it should return `True` if the button is visible otherwise it should be `False`, currently it only returns `True` even when I'm no longer calling the `render` function. So I'd like to ask for some help on how to fix this.

I have only included the absolutely necessary parts of the code in to replicate the problem.

Okay, I have tried everything I could come up with, I even asked an AI, to make the function work, but none of it worked. I'll leave what I've tried at the bottom.

Here is part of the class I made for making screens and drawing to them: (Included are three classes; `Draw`, `DrawRectangle`, and `DrawButton`. The others are not needed.)

```py
class Draw:
    def __init__(self, width=800, height=600):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.font = Font()
        # Screen setup
        self.display = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Clicker Game")
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    
    def Rect(self, x, y, width, height, padding=(20, 20), border_color=BLACK, background=WHITE):
        return DrawRectangle(self, x, y, width, height, padding, border_color, background)
    
    def Button(self, text, x, y, seperate=(0, 0), text_color=BLACK, border_color=BLACK, background=WHITE):
        return DrawButton(self, text, x, y, seperate, text_color, border_color, background)
    
    def MultiButton(self, *args):
        return DrawMultiButton(self, *args)
    
    def Tabs(self, pos=(10, 1000), tabs=[]):
        return Tabbed(self, pos, tabs)


class DrawRectangle:
    """Draw rectangle on screen."""
    def __init__(self, screen, x, y, width, height, padding=(20, 20), border_color=BLACK, background=WHITE):
        self.screen = screen
        self.border_color = border_color
        self.background = background
        self.draw(x, y, width, height, padding)
        
    def draw(self, x, y, width, height, padding=None, border_color=None, background=None):
        self.border_color = border_color or self.border_color
        self.background = background or self.background
        holdPad = None
        if padding is None:
            holdPad = self.padding
            padding = 0
        self.padding = {
            "top": 20,
            "bottom": 20,
            "left": 20,
            "right": 20
        }
        count = 0
        padding_keys = list(self.padding.keys())
        for i in range(len(padding_keys)):
            key = padding_keys[i]
            if isinstance(padding, tuple):
                self.padding[key] = padding[count] if padding[count] is not None else 20
                if len(padding) == 2:
                    if i == 1:
                        count += 1
                elif len(padding) == 3:
                    if i != 2:
                        count += 1
                elif len(padding) == 4:
                    count += 1
            else:
                self.padding[key] = padding if padding is not None else 20
        
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        
        self.height = height+self.padding["top"]+self.padding["bottom"]
        self.width = width+self.padding["left"]+self.padding["right"]
        
        self.box = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
        if holdPad is not None:
            self.padding = holdPad
        return self
    
    def render(self, to=None):
        if to is None:
            to = self.screen.display
        pygame.draw.rect(to, self.background, self.box)
        pygame.draw.rect(to, self.border_color, self.box, 2)
        return self.box


class DrawButton:
    """Draw button on screen."""
    def __init__(self, screen, text, x, y, seperate=(0, 0), text_color=BLACK, border_color=BLACK, background=WHITE):
        self.screen = screen
        self.border_color = border_color
        self.background = background
        
        rect = self.screen.Rect(x+seperate[0], y+seperate[1], 20, 14, (20), border_color, background)
        
        self.height = rect.height
        self.width = rect.width
        
        self.button_rect = rect.draw(x+seperate[0], y+seperate[1], self.width, self.height)
    
    def onEvent(self, event, pos, handle):
        if self.isVisible() and self.button_rect.box.collidepoint(pos):
            return handle(self)
        return None
    
    def isVisible(self):
        return (
            0 <= self.button_rect.box.left < self.screen.display.get_width() and
            0 <= self.button_rect.box.top < self.screen.display.get_height() and
            0 <= self.button_rect.box.right < self.screen.display.get_width() and
            0 <= self.button_rect.box.bottom < self.screen.display.get_height()
        )
    
    def render(self, to=None):
        if to is None:
            to = self.screen.display
        self.button_rect.render(to)
        return self.button_rect.box
```

Now here is some of my main code:

```py
# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

# Constants
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GRAY = (200, 200, 200)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
FPS = 60

draw = Draw(WIDTH, HEIGHT)


def drawMain():
    scrollablesMain()
    

def scrollablesMain(scroll=None, pos=(0, 0)):
    global click_button
    if scroll is None:
        to = None
        scroll_val_y = 0-pos[1]
        scroll_val_x = 0-pos[0]
    else:
        to = scroll.scrollable_area
        scroll_val_y = scroll.value["y"]
        scroll_val_x = scroll.value["x"]
        
    # Draw clicker button
    click_button = draw.Button(f"Click for ${click_value}", 40-scroll_val_x, 100-scroll_val_y, text_color=WHITE, background=BLACK)
    click_button.render(to)


tabs = draw.Tabs(tabs=[ # this is how the different pages are displayed
    ("main", drawMain), # (default selected) if selected will display the main page, i.e. where the clicker is.
    ("upgrades", drawUpgrades),
    ("achievements", drawAchievements),
    ("milestones", drawMilestones)
])

# Main game loop
running = True
while running:
    draw.display.fill(WHITE)
    
    # Event handling
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            click_button.onEvent(event, pos, lambda me: addM(click_value))
            tabs.onEvent(event, pos)
    tabs.render() # draws the buttons to be able to select the pages
    tabs.display() # just calls the function given to tabs i.e. if the selected page is main then tabs.display is calling drawMain()
    pygame.display.flip()
    draw.clock.tick(FPS)

# Quit Pygame
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Now here is all that I have tried to make `isVisible()` work: (Obviously none of it worked)

```py
self.screen.display.get_rect().colliderect(self.button_rect.box)
```

```py
test_rect = self.button_rect.box
screen = self.screen.display
(0 <= test_rect.left < screen.get_width() and
        0 <= test_rect.top < screen.get_height() or
        0 <= test_rect.right < screen.get_width() and
        0 <= test_rect.bottom < screen.get_height())
```

```py
test_rect = self.button_rect.box
screen = self.screen.display
(test_rect.right < 0 or
        test_rect.bottom < 0 or
        test_rect.left > screen.get_width() or
        test_rect.top > screen.get_height())
```

Is there any way to make `isVisible` work the way I intended.

Comment: It is possible for `button_rect` to be within the bounds of the screen even if it's not being rendered. If you want to consider whether or not it's being rendered, you'll need to do that manually. Pygame won't automatically edit your `button_rect` if you don't call `render()`.

Comment: @Rabbid76 They're not asking about (just) collision. They've already tried `colliderect`. They're asking how to tell if the button is currently *visible*. They don't want to return `False` only when the button is outside the screen; they also want to return `False` when it's within the screen but something else has been rendered overtop it (or if it hasn't been rendered at all).

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there is a dupe target for that too, but I'm unfamiliar enough with PyGame that I'm not sure what it would be.

Comment: @Gaberocksall So, there isn't a way to just have the function `isVisible` without having some sort of variable out side of the class that is being changed when I click to change to a new tab?

Comment: Your code isn't a self-contained [MRE], so I have no idea where `Tabbed` is defined, but it seems likely it knows which tab it's currently displaying, right? If you give the button attributes that point to the collection of tabs and identify the tab it belongs to, you could check something like `self.tabs.is_selected(self.tab)`. (This is pseudocode, obviously, but hopefully it gets the idea across.)

Comment: If you edit your question so that the code is as minimal as possible *that can still be run as-is* and reproduce the issue (including all necessary imports), it would stand a much better chance of being reopened.

Comment: I found the answer to my question, all I needed to do was make a variable, `self._vis` and set it to false in `isVisible` and set it to true in `render` and I can't believe that they would say that this question was a duplicate, when it had nothing to do with a rectangle being out side of the screen.

Comment: Glad you figured out a solution! If and when this gets reopened, you can post and accept your own answer.

Comment: P.S. The code shown still isn't an MRE, since it can't be run as-is.